# How to require Kerberos authentication on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, configuration, kerberos

I have created an Active Directory Domain Controller-integrated SharePoint site on Azure using the new Create SharePoint Farm feature.

I want to change it to require Kerberos.  Does anyone know how to actually do this?  I have done a lot of Internet searches and can't find anything clear on how to configure SharePoint to require Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

To configure the Kerberos, you have to perform following steps.

- [Configure SQL Server for kerberos Authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/echarran/archive/2010/02/11/howto-configure-sharepoint-2010-for-kerberos.aspx)
- [Create DNS entry for your web application](http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=43)
- Create SPN for the DNS(you will use to access the SharePoint)
- Make Changes in Central admin and change authentication To Kerberos.
- Enable Constrained Delegation

here is complete guide and step by step process from MSFT white paper.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23176